# how to get count of months for unique ID from transaction table in pandas dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
ID  month   amnt    flg
123 Jan       10    0
123 feb       20    1
123 mar       30    1
124 jan       15    1
124 feb       15    1
124 mar       20    1
125 feb       20       1
```

I have the above dataframe. The flag is created for customers having more than 15k. the data has 3 months data so creating below table out of  3 months.I'm expecting something like below

```
ID      Months
123        3
124         3
125         1
```

I tried creating flag for each month and then tried group by I'd and month. But that did not work.
I tried

```
df.groupby(['ID'])['month'].count()
```

Need your help in python.

Comment: are you trying `groupby(['ID', 'month'])` and sum `amt`? I'm not sure how you got that expected output

Comment: Just a single row as an output??

Comment: That is my expected output.

Comment: I didn't get the logic. is 2 0 1  a count of flag?

Comment: @pygirl  it's count of ID's

Comment: How flag is playing role in the expected output?

Comment: If flag is >= 15 than 1

Comment: What actually do you want to get as an output? How is the answer I gave you doesn't help. Please mention what you actually want to achieve

Comment: This will do: `df.groupby(['ID'])['month'].apply(lambda x: x.count())`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
li = [1,2,3]
x = df.groupby(['ID'])['month'].apply(lambda x: x.count()).values
y = {f'month{p}of3':sum(x == p) for p in li}
df = pd.DataFrame([y])
```

---

**df:**

```
    month1of3   month2of3   month3of3
0   1           0           2
```

Comment: I'm getting invalid syntax. What is li ?

Comment: @AravindBalakrishnan: check now. li= no of months `1,2,3`